# Determining probability of a point's membership to multiple circles

Tags: python, data-science, probability

I have a list of the centers and radii of about 10 circles in a plane. I also have a list of ~100 points scattered around the plane. By eye, some of the points are very nearby or even inside a circle, while others are very far away from any circle. Some of the circles are also very close together, with many points also existing in this area.

The data are fairly straightforward:

Circles:

```
    X         Y            Radius
0  -19.370525 -20.997882   22.486245
1  -33.666281  15.665494   8.487290
2  -24.816294 -47.834261   6.830408
```

Points:

```
            X          Y
0  -33.839499 -12.905389
1  -34.018966  17.154616
2  -34.019669 -22.445386
```

I'm essentially looking for a way to find which points are the most likely to be associated with a given circle. I would also need to be able to find when no points are likely to be associated with a circle, and identify when a point is likely to be associated with multiple circles. Ideally, this would also be able to account for the fact that different circles have different radii when finding the likelihood of association.

I've tried a few different things:

1. Gaussian Mixture Model:
   I think this might be the totally wrong direction, as it would find clusters of points but doesn't incorporate the circles at all.

```
    from astroML.plotting.tools import draw_ellipse   

    point_array = np.array([circles['X'],circles['Y']).T
    gmm = GaussianMixture(10).fit(point_array)
    log_dens = gmm.score_samples(point_array)     

    gmm_x = gmm.means_[:,0]
    gmm_y = gmm.means_[:,1]
    gmm_weights = gmm.weights_

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(gmm_x,gmm_y,c='k')
    ax.scatter(points['X'],points['Y'],c='r')
    for mu, C, w in zip(gmm.means_,gmm.covariances_,gmm.weights_):
        draw_ellipse(mu,C,ax=ax,fc='none',ec='k')
```

2. Gaussian Naive Bayes:
   So this is just the start of what this should be and probably has lots of errors.  I'm assuming a Gaussian distribution around every circle, but I think I am doing something wrong because the probabilities of membership for most points to circles is on the order of 1e-100, even when they are very nearby. Also, I didn't have a good way to estimate the error on the circle so I just assumed 10% error, which is also likely problematic.

```
    p_circ_point = []

    for i in range(0,10):

        p_member_loc = []

        circ_x = circles['X'].values[i] 
        circ_y = circles['Y'].values[i]

        circ_rad = circles['Radius'].values[i]

        clus_err = 0.1 * circ_rad

        for j in range(len():

            point_x = points['X'][j]
            clump_y = points['Y'][j]

            delta_x = circ_x - point_x
            delta_y = circ_y - circ_y

            dist_clus_clump = np.sqrt(delta_x**2 + delta_y**2)
            p_l_m = (1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*clus_err)) * \
                    np.e**(-(dist_clus_clump**2)/(2*clus_err**2))

            p_member_loc = np.append(p_member_loc,p_l_m)

        p_circ_point = np.append(p_circ_point,p_member_loc)
```

I've also tried a few other things to similar lack of success.  If you have any ideas or suggestions it would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: please, add some details about what exactly you have tried so far. Also, a geometry library like shapely will be more pertinent to your problem. https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/

Comment: Hi, I updated to add more details. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're going in a workable direction. About the second idea, I dunno if I would call it naive Bayes, but the label doesn't matter. Anyway what you want is p(c_k|x) where x is a given point and c_k is the k'th circle. That's just p(x|c_k) p(c_k) / Z where p(x|c_k) is your Gaussian bump with mean = center of circle and s.d. = radius or something like that. The normalizing factor Z is just the sum of p(x|c_k) p(c_k) over all k. Even if each value is very small, normalizing will make them more reasonable. Some might be near 0 but some will be larger, since they need to add up to 1.

Comment: Thank you, that's extremely helpful! I implemented that without any problems and have a result that I'm happy with.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is vague. How are these points and circles defined?

If you have simple definitions, isn't this simply a matter of deciding what circle a point falls into, or compute the ratios between the point's distance to the circles' centres and the circles' radii?

If `radius(c1) / distance_to_centre(p1, c1) > 1`, the point `p1` is in the circle `c1`. And if you compute `radius(cx) / distance_to_centre(p, cx)` for each circle cx, whichever has the highest value will be be the circle you're after.

(Note: careful if the point falls on the circle's centre, you'll get a divide by zero if you don't check for it)

If you provide some sample data, the code should be straightforward.

Comment: I updated to include sample data and what I've tried so far.  What you've suggested is a good idea.